# Open Menu from a button click

Tags: java, android

I have this code for showing a Menu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Email_settings:
 //    startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
    return true;
    case R.id.Help_settings:
//     startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
    return true;
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The code works fine when pressing the device options button.

How can i open the menu on a button click from inside my screen and not the device options button?

Comment: you can use Popup menu as a menu which will open on button click.

Comment: or use `PopupMenu` which is supported down to API 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call

```
openOptionsMenu();
```

on Click event

Answer (score 1):

Use Activity.openOptionsMenu() method.

[Docs reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29)

Be sure to use this method only after options menu is instanciated(onCreateOptionsMenu was already executed)